# How to get location field from linkedin api while fetching network updates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api, linkedin-api

I want to fetch location of person and connections so how should I specify fields for this purpose?

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates:(update-content:(person:(id,headline,location)))?type=CONN
```

If I'll make another calls for just getting location, it will be very costly for me, as it will require to make extra calls for each of new connection and will increase number of calls exponentially. So, I want some solution using which I can get location in network updates API call itself.

**EDIT:** And another thing I need is to check about the privacy setting of connections. As per my knowledge, linkedin doesn't provide any api which returns that which connection allows to see updates and which are not. So, when I try to get network update for a particular connection, it returns error that this user doesn't allow public to see updates. If I want to check this thing before call network updates API, how can I do it in Ruby Language.

OR

Let me know some way to pass multiple dynamic IDs while calling linkedin API.

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving person data associated with a Network Update, it appears that [only the basic fields are available](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/15809#comment-15809). The solution would be to get the id for the person and make a second call to the [Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api):

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=12345:(first-name,last-name,connections,location)
```

Comment: I understand this but I need some other solution in which I don't need to make another call

Comment: Can you tell me how to make linkedin API query with dynamic multiple IDs in ruby?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, linkedin doesn't provide any API for this purpose. You have to make multiple calls for this purpose. But you should make these calls in chunks to avoid timeout issues.

[Reference](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api)

Answer (score 0):

Try this api

```
    `String url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,first-name,last-name,location,picture-url,positions:(title,company:(name)))"; `
```